# how to update subscription trail period in paypal using rest api for react.js

Tags: reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

How can I update my subscription trial period for a monthly plan using rest API for react.
I have searched in the rest api section but didnt find any.

Answer (score 0):

The [Update Subscription API call](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_patch) allows patching the /plan/billing_cycles object. The details of what is possible are documented there so I'm not sure what your question is about.